# How to decide which mode to use for 'kaiming_normal' initialization

Tags: initialization, pytorch

I have read several codes that do layer initialization using `nn.init.kaiming_normal_()` of PyTorch. Some codes use the `fan in` mode which is the default. Of the many examples, one can be found [here](https://github.com/Xiaoming-Yu/RAGAN/blob/master/models/model.py#L50) and shown below.

```
init.kaiming_normal(m.weight.data, a=0, mode='fan_in')
```

However, sometimes I see people using the `fan out` mode as seen [here](https://github.com/liminn/ICNet-pytorch/blob/master/models/base_models/resnetv1b.py#L126) and shown below.

```
if isinstance(m, nn.Conv2d):
                nn.init.kaiming_normal_(m.weight, mode='fan_out', nonlinearity='relu')
```

Can someone give me some guidelines or tips to help me decide which mode to select? Further I am working on image super resolutions and denoising tasks using PyTorch and which mode will be more beneficial.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.init.html#torch.nn.init.kaiming_normal_):

> Choosing 'fan_in' preserves the magnitude of the variance of the
>   weights in the forward pass. Choosing 'fan_out' preserves the
>   magnitudes in the backwards pass.

and according to [Delving deep into rectifiers: Surpassing human-level performance on ImageNet classification - He, K. et al. (2015)](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1502.01852.pdf):

> We  note  that  it  is  sufficient  to  use  either  Eqn.(14)  or
>   Eqn.(10)

where Eqn.(10) and Eqn.(14) are `fan_in` and `fan_out` appropriately. Furthermore:

> This means that if the initialization properly scales the backward
>   signal, then this is also the case for the forward signal; and vice
>   versa. For all models in this paper, both forms can make them converge

**so all in all it doesn't matter much** but it's more about what you are after. I assume that if you suspect your backward pass might be more "chaotic" (greater variance) it is worth changing the mode to `fan_out`. This might happen when the loss oscillates a lot (e.g. very easy examples followed by very hard ones).

Correct choice of `nonlinearity` is more important, where `nonlinearity` is the activation you are using **after** the layer you are initializaing currently. Current defaults set it to `leaky_relu` with `a=0`, which is effectively the same as `relu`. If you are using `leaky_relu` you should change `a` to it's slope.

Comment: Thankyou @Szymon. One more clarification. If I decide to use 'ReLu' with 'fan in' mode which is the default initialization done by PyTorch to conv layers (if no initialization is mentioned in code). In such a case is it still good to do explicit initialization in my code? If no, then does it mean to explicitly instruct PyTorch to do kaiming initialization if and only if I decide to say use Leaky Relu or want to use the 'fan out' mode? I ask this because I see many codes writing explicitly to use 'fan in' with 'Relu' although this is the default behaviour of PyTorch.

Comment: IIUC; the thing is initialization is mostly overlooked in DL AFAIK and quite often run with standard methods (kaiming, xavier), maybe mentioned briefly. IMO if the initialization is important in the context of your work you should be explicit about it. If it's nowhere near central to what you're doing it should be skipped as it adds unnecessary noise for the reader (unless you tinker with it in PyTorch's non-default way). That's just my opinion though, you can do either and both will be fine.

Comment: Is there a citation giving the reasoning behind the difference in kaiming_normal across nonlinearity typles? The He paper just seems to focus on ReLU.

Comment: @SzymonMaszke Is there any reason we care about the forward propagated signal to not vanish/explode? The only reason I can think of, is that the activations appear in the backpropagation rule for update of weights.

Comment: It does matter more than people initially expect. It does highly depend on your activation since the feature statistics change to depending on the activation. Ideally, you want the variance of features to not change between layers during initialization to prevent your features from growing/shrinking. People generally overlook how important initialization is. The famous paper by Xavier/Bengio made this clear http://proceedings.mlr.press/v9/glorot10a/glorot10a.pdf, look at Figure 6/7 to get a visualization of why it matters.